# /usr/bin/docker-current: missing signature key

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run the MySQL docker image using the below command

```
docker run -d --name mysqldb -p 3306:3306 -v db_data:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mysql:latest
```

However, it is failing with the error

```
/usr/bin/docker-current: missing signature key.
```

[image]

Does anyone have a suggestion?

docker --version
Docker version 1.13.1, build 7d71120/1.13.1

Comment: I have resolved it by upgrading the docker version, seems the issue was with the docker version https://github.com/louislam/uptime-kuma/issues/3777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

old docker version, just use official repo

[root@docker ~]# docker -v
Docker version 26.0.0, build 2ae903e